# php while statement causing 500 error

Tags: php

I'm completely stumped here.  I've written the code below and when I view the page I get a 500 error.  Via process of commenting out select lines one by one I was able to find that the while statement is causing the error...could anyone tell me what could possible be wrong with my code?

```
<?php 
                $rQuery = "SELECT * FROM roles ORDER BY roleName ASC";
                $rResult = mysql_query($rQuery);

                if (!$rResult){
                    echo 'Query Error <br>' . $rQuery;
                    exit;
                }

            ?>
            <p>
                <select name="roleaddid" id="roleaddid" >

                  <?php while ($roles = mysql_fetch_array($rResult)){ ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $roles['roleId'] ?>"><?php echo $roles['roleName'] ?></option>

                    <? } // end while ?>

                </select>

            </p>
```

thanks for any insight...

Comment: do you have short tags enabled? I noticed your ending brace is in <? ?>, not <?php ?>

Comment: @donutdan4114 make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix the `<? ?>` around your ending brace.

Change to `<?php ?>`

Answer (score 0):

donutdan definately gets the answer, you need short tags enabled.... also if your using short tags like so: `<? echo $blank ?>` you should still end your echo with a semi colon, and even better yet, call the variable this way

```
<?=$variable?>
```

that way you don't have to echo every time like that....

Comment: The semicolon is optional before a `?>`.  I personally prefer it not be there, for short fragments.

Comment: i know it's optional, but i always prefer to follow specified syntax, even a if conditional statement with one action bugs me w/o brackets, really i'm just showing you don't need to echo with <?=$variable?>... definately makes things easier

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

            //add your mysql connect
            $rQuery = "SELECT * FROM roles ORDER BY roleName ASC";
            $rResult = mysql_query($rQuery);

            if (!$rResult){
                echo 'Query Error <br>' . $rQuery;
                exit;
            }

        ?>
        <p>
            <select name="roleaddid" id="roleaddid" >

              <?php while ($roles = mysql_fetch_array($rResult)){ ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $roles['roleId'] ?>"><?php echo $roles['roleName'] ?></option>

                <?php } // end while ?>

            </select>

        </p>
```